# how to play audio in earpiece in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, kotlin

I have an app where I have to play audio in earpiece of phone and I tried some code but I could not able to play sound in earpiece. There was no sound was playing in earpiece can you help me with that?

**Note:-** The code here is for react-native app and below module is native module of app.

**Here is my code**

```
package com.modules;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class EarpieceModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName(
    ) {
        return "Earpiece Module";
    }

private final ReactContext context;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public EarpieceModule(ReactContext context){
    this.context = context;
}


@ReactMethod
public void playWithMedia(String path){

    boolean isPlaying = false;
    if (!isPlaying) {
        try {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getReactApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path));
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@ReactMethod
public void stopMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
}
```